# customizing TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm new to latex, I'm thankful if someone can give me an example script to customize TOC that looks like

Chapter 1.XXXXXX                                                            (1-15)

1.1 Introduction 1.2 xxxxxxxx 1.3 xxxxxxxxxx 1.4 xxxxxxx ...............

Chapter 2.xxxxxxx

2.1 xxxxx ......                                                           (16-30)

because the (default) TOC appears to be very large for my book, since it arranges the section name row-by-row.

Answer (score 11):

An easy way to save space would be typesetting the table of contents in two or more columns. I've seen that some times, but I don't remember any book lining up several section titles in a row.

If you choose to typeset in two or more columns, that can be done easily using the [`multitoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multitoc) package. You may use even more columns than the default two. Have a look at the [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ms/multitoc.pdf) for an example.

Simply adding

```
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
```

would already show the table of contents in two columns. And, for example, add

```
\renewcommand*{\multicolumntoc}{3}
```

if you wish to have three columns.

Comment: A good example of a 'compact' table of contents is the `titlesec` and `titletoc` documentation. It can be a good alternative to use this style rather than the `multitoc`.

Comment: .. and thanks to you for your countless tips!

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned an example derived from the [titlesec/titletoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) manual.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\titlecontents*{section}[1.5em]{\small}{\thecontentslabel. }{}{, \thecontentspage}[ --- ]
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

As always, the [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution.

Comment: This is a good solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. Now i can use this with some modification. Again is it possible to customize the page no. to specify the range, like (2-12). i.e, first and last page no. of the chapter.

Comment: At the moment I'm not aware of such a solution.