# On the tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

I know that we can use "\tableofcontents" to list all the contents of the article. However, if there are so many subsection for example, how then can I get the contents as follows:

1. complex nummbers....................................................................................................................3
   1.1 complex numbers (3) 1.2 complex plane (5) 1.3 the modules and arguments (7) 1.4 the powers and squares (13) 1.5 conjugates (16)

Here subsection 1.1 in on the page 3, etc.

Comment: There's [`titletoc` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) that enables ToC styling. It's not the easiest package to use (since ToC formatting is not the easiest thing to do). Maybe if you tried this package and when you come across a problem, you may of course ask a bit more specific thing...

Comment: @tohecz I have used "\usepackage{titletoc}". But what shall I do then to make the tableofcontents just as above?

Comment: See the question I've linked above, and especially [Thorsten Donig's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6457/11002)